# Windows application packaging project does not provide option to uninstall previous installed package before installing the new one

Tags: wpf, windows-installer, packaging

I use Windows Application Packaging Project to generate MSIXBUNDLE for my WPF app.

App installed failed with error message: Windows cannot install package xxxxxx_3.8.3.0_neutral~_hijkl because a different package xxxxxxx_3.8.2.0_neutral~_abcde r with the same name is already installed. Remove package xxxxxx_3.8.2.0_neutral~_abcde before installing. (0x80073cf3)

I think the reason is that I signed the new package (3.8,3) with a new EV code signing certificate. Does WAP tool support option to uninstall previous package? Under the project property tab "Debug" ->"Start option", there is a check box for "Uninstall and then re-install my package. All information about the application state is deleted". But enable it does not seem to do the job.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> "Uninstall and then re-install my package. All information about the application state is deleted"

I think this option is useful only for debugging purposes. It sounds like an option to remove a previous copy of the package (that has the same version and product name). So, this does not help with removing older versions.

For MSIX packages, you don't top configure anything specific in the package to trigger the removal of a previous version, as you used to do with an MSI. This is handled automatically by the OS.

But the OS needs to somehow understand which package to remove and I suspect the digital certificate is part of that check. Just manually remove the old version, install the new one, and then build a test version (3.8.4) to confirm if the different certificate was the problem.

Comment: Yes, installing a newer version (3.8.4) signed with same certificate as 3.8.3, is successful.